# do 2 imported scripts see each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net mvc view where I'm referencing some jQuery libraries, as well as a script that I've created.

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EditEmployeeScripts.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my question is, does my own custom script (the last one) see the other two jQuery libraries that are referenced? In other words, can I use jQuery in my custom script or do I have to somehow reference the jQuery libraries inside my script as well?

Comment: Yes you can use jquery in your script - just try it and see!

Comment: Mostly depends how you include your libraries (see js module mechanism), but answer most likely is yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is loaded synchronously by default in the DOM.  Meaning, that the order that you load the scripts in your page, is the order that they are available.  As long as your script file is loaded after the jQuery files, then all globally available functions in the jQuery files would be available to your JavaScript file.  This applies to all JavaScript files and libraries, not only to jQuery.  However, if a script file is set to load asynchronously, this would not necessarily be the case.

Comment: I'd add a little note about scope and only globally available functions and variables being visible.